# omniauth-identity, on_failure and uid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm using omniauth-identity. When the user tries to sign in and fail, I want to redirect him to a different place if only the password is incorrect.

Right now it's looking like this:

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = -> env do

  if env['omniauth.error.strategy'].name != 'identity'
    OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint.new(env).redirect_to_failure 
  end


  #if user
    IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env)
  #else
   # HomeController.action(:index).call(env)
  end

end
```

I can't seem to obtain any other information (in this case, the uid) beside the strategy, error and origin. Is it possible to obtain this information?